# Ajax autocomplete extender not firing

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use the autocomplete extender and when I start type in the textbox nothing happens (doesnt suggest) anything. Any ideas why? Also I dont think return customers.To Array will work?

```
    Imports System.Web.Services
    Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
    Imports System.ComponentModel
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient

    ' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the
    following line.
    ' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
    <System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
    <System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
    <ToolboxItem(False)> _
    Public Class AutoComplete1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetCompletionList(prefixText As String, count As Integer) As String()
        Try
            Dim Con As SqlConnection
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand
            Con = New SqlConnection
                Con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=Database;"
            Con.Open()

            cmd = New SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = Con
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, School, Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, TIN FROM tblschools Where School LIKE @School + '%'"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@School", prefixText)
            Dim customers As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            While reader.Read
                customers.Add(reader("School").ToString 

            End While
            Con.Close()

            Return customers.ToArray
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Function


    End Class





    <%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
```

Here is the design of the aspx page:

```
<asp:ServiceReference Path="*.asmx" />


</Services>

    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" 
        DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx"  
        ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the network console?

Comment: When you open the developer tools of your browser (F12 or ctrl+Q depending on yours), you usually get a "net" or "Network" tab in which you can see the requests and the responses to it. I strongly suggest you use those developer tools anyway, they can be quite usefull !

Comment: I set it as the start page it is not firing, I set a break point and it never hits it?

Comment: I got it to fire had to enable post back but it still does not show a dropdown menu of suggestions?

Comment: If you allow me some piece of advice, there are a few things you always gotta check when having an issue with .NET : automatic postback ? Viewstate ? Wich page or controls events are firing in which order ? Am I client-side or server-side ? (valid for all web languages...) That's a kind of quite useful "checklist" when debugging... and of course it can become way broader ;-)